# Powershell script to extract the deleted Resources from the Activity logs for the past 1 month

Tags: azure, powershell, cloud, azure-powershell

I'm trying to extract all the resources which are deleted in azure environment for the past 1 month.

Powershell script to extract the deleted Resources from the Activity logs for the past 1 month.

I've tried to use : Get-AzLog -StartTime $StartTime -EndTime $EndTime | Where-Object { $_.OperationName.StartsWith("Delete") }

But is this giving all the deleted resources list?

Answer (score 0):

***Firstly, I ran the below Powershell script to get the operation names in the Azure portal.***

**Script** :

```
Get-AzActivityLog -StartTime $startTime -EndTime $endTime | Select-Object -ExpandProperty OperationName -Unique
```

**Output** :t

[image]
[image]

I tried the below **power shell script** to get all **Deleted Resources** for the past 1 month in the Azure portal.

**Script** :

```
$endTime = Get-Date
$startTime = $endTime.AddMonths(-1)

$deletedResourceEvents = Get-AzActivityLog -StartTime $startTime -EndTime $endTime `
    | Where-Object { $_.OperationName.StartsWith("Delete") } 

$deletedResourceEvents
```

**Output** :

[image]
[image]

Use the below script to get only one deleted Resource. I tried to get the **deleted Virtual Machine**.

**Script** :

```
$deletedResourceEvents = Get-AzActivityLog -StartTime $startTime -EndTime $endTime `
    | Where-Object { $_.OperationName.StartsWith("Delete Virtual Machine") } 

$deletedResourceEvents
```

**Output** :

[image]